# data-value de un select no me trae el dato (undefined) jquery laravel

Tags: jquery

necesito obtener el valor "cantidad" que viene en un array desde el controlador hasta la vista donde cargo un select, entonces al seelccionar una opcion del select necesito mostrar la cantidad en un input para lo cual estoy usando en el select un data (data-cantidad) para luego con jquery en el evento change recuperar el valor y asignarlo al input, pero me da undefined como se ve en la imagen (puede verse que en el data recibo bien la cantidad junto al nombre del producto y otros datos):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Funcion en el script:

```
function cargarMateriales(tecnico_id,servicio_id){

                $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('/logistica/materiales/devoluciones/mat') }}"+`/${tecnico_id}`+`/${servicio_id}`,
                method:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(result){
                    console.log('El result es:',result)

                    var opciones = '';

                    var opciones = '<option value="" disabled="disabled">--Seleccione Material a Transferir--</option>';
                    result.data.forEach(element => {
                    opciones += `<option value="${element.material_id} data-cantidad="${element.cantidad}">${element.nombre_producto}</option>`;
                     });

                    $("#materiales").html(opciones);

                    }
            });
```

Y el evento change en mi vista:

```
  $('#materiales').on('change', function(){
            //var cantidad = $('select#materiales').find(':selected').data('cantidad');
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var cantidad= $('option:selected', this).attr('data-cantidad');
             console.log(cantidad);
            $('#stock').val(cantidad);
        });
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: Tenés un error de sintaxis. Revisa las comillas de los options.

Comment: Te falta cerrar el `value` con comillas: **`<option value="${element.material_id}"`** Y, por otra parte, la sintaxis habitual para obtener atributos `data-` no es usar `attr` sino `data`  directamente, por ejemplo: `var cantidad= $('option:selected', this).data('cantidad');`  O, mejor aún: **`$(this).find(':selected').data('cantidad');`**
Revisa [la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key) al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO: para alguien mas que pueda necesitarlo, como me comentaron me faltaba cerrar una comilla y en la llamada igual estaba mal, finalmente me quedo asi:

Evento ONCHANGE:

```
 $('#materiales').on('change', function(){
        var cantidad = $(this).find(':selected').data('cantidad');
        $('#stock').val(cantidad);
 });
```

Y el select:

```
<option value="${element.material_id}" data-cantidad="${element.cantidad}">${element.nombre_producto}</option>`;
```